# Can't get json ajax code to work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is driving me insane. My code is working fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason Internet Explorer refuses to output it.

My code is:

```
function loaditem() {

    $('.html').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var datakey = id.substring(id.indexOf('-') + 1, id.length);
        var divpointx = id.substring(id.indexOf('-') + 1, id.length);
        var divpoint = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var resultpoint = "#result-" + divpoint;
        var ip = new Object();
        ip.session_id = "312fdfwf1343r";
        var c_id = JSON.stringify(ip);
        var module = "module1";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            data: {
                "c_id": divpoint
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
                var result = ""
                $.each(obj, function () {
                    result = result + "<p>TEST</p>";
                });
                result = result + ""
                $("#result-" + id.substring(id.indexOf('-') + 1, id.length)).empty().html(result);

            }
        });
    });
};
```

Does anyone know why the code isn't working? i'd be eternally grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Why identical code to assign `datakey` and `divpointx` and why do you create `c_id` and then not use it.

Comment: Sounds like a browser support issue.

Comment: Have you attached an error handler to your ajax call to see if it is reporting an error?

Comment: does it throw an error?

Comment: Is it sending precisely what you think it is? E.g., check the assumptions of your request. Is it returning what you think it should be? E.g., check the assumptions of your response. You've not provided much detail other than the code.

Comment: The code you posted is not enough for reproducing the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 how can I attach an error handler? I'm quite new to ajax/json. The code I use to trigger the function is this in the header: 
$(function(){
 loaditem();
});
And this in the body: <a href="#" id="html-61625"  class="ajaxButton actionbtn.list" style="float:left; "><div class="wholder"><div class="holder" style="color:#333">Title</div></div></a><div class="centeralign"><div id="result-61625"></div>

Comment: You're attaching a click handler to the **class** 'html'. May I ask you where is that class?

Comment: How to attach an error handler is well described in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.  Not something we should repeat here.  Also, multiline code is not readable in comments.  Do not do that.  If you need to show additional code, then use the "edit" link and add it to your question and then add a comment to tell people you added it.

Comment: Based on the html you posted I can make some guesses. Instead of ".html" do you mean attaching the handler to "#html-61625" ? I see in your code you split the id by dash and get the number then you put the result in "#result-61625". The first issue I see with this code is you're not specifying dataType in the ajax call. That may cause jQuery being unaware on how to parse the result. What Content-Type are you returning from server?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I actually figured out what was causing the issue. I added basic authentication to the php file that generated the json which caused a security error with IE. Referenced like this in the ajax cell: 
    url: http://username:password@url.com/json.php
Does anyone have a recommendation as to how to best secure a php file that generates json?